# Change HTML image source in a div with javascript when click on label not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, src

I need to change the image inside a div in HTML when clicking a label. I don't think I need to use jquery for that, I want to use just javascript. After some research, it looks simple, all the answers are the same, but I can't get it to work. I know the function when clicking the label works because the label change color, but the image doesn't change and I don't get any syntax error. I'm using chrome. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

this is HTML/CSS code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="slc_on_label">
    <img src=https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/800/cpsprodpb/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg>
  </div>

  <style>
    #slc_on_label img {
      position:fixed;
      width:5.5%;
      left:10%;
      top:10%;
    }
  </style>

  <label class = "button" id="button" onclick="run(this)">0</label>

  <style>
  .button {background-color:Powderblue;
          font-size: 5vw;
        }
   </style>

  <script src="question.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
function run(button) {
  document.getElementById("slc_on_label").src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313_1280.jpg";
  button.style = "background-color:red";
}
```

Comment: you need to put the id slc_on_label on the image not on the div...you are trying to change the src of the div? the div div does not have a source.

Comment: That true! thank you @Talmacel Marian Silviu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the `src` attribute on `<div id="slc_on_label">` instead of the `<img>` inside it.

You can use `document.querySelector()` to select the image inside the `div`:

```
document.querySelector("#slc_on_label img").src =
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313_1280.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function run(button) {
  document.querySelector('slc_on_label img').src =
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313_1280.jpg';
  button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Also not breaking the button style.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #slc_on_label img {
            position: fixed;
            width: 5.5%;
            left: 10%;
            top: 10%;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: Powderblue;
            font-size: 5vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="slc_on_label">
        <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/800/cpsprodpb/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg">
    </div>

    <label class="button" id="button" onclick="run(this)">0</label>

    <script>
        function run(button) {
            document.querySelector("#slc_on_label img").setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313_1280.jpg');
            button.style = "background-color:red";
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The way you wrote your code, your are trying to change the src of the div. To fix that, find the the element img correctly using the same selector you already wrote by using document.querySelector("#slc_on_label img"). Now with the right element selected you can change the src value.